# Rename (add suffix to) every key except 2 in every object in array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

We have the following javascript array:

```
[
  { team: 1, stat1: 17, stat2: 25, var1: 'okay', var3: 'nah', here: 24 },
  { team: 1, stat1: 17, stat2: 25, var1: 'okay', var3: 'nah', here: 24 },
  { team: 1, stat1: 17, stat2: 25, var1: 'okay', var3: 'nah', here: 24 }
]
```

and we are looking to add the suffix `Agst` to every key other than the `team` key, such that our output is:

```
[
  { team: 1, stat1Agst: 17, stat2Agst: 25, var1Agst: 'okay', var3Agst: 'nah', hereAgst: 24 },
  { team: 1, stat1Agst: 17, stat2Agst: 25, var1Agst: 'okay', var3Agst: 'nah', hereAgst: 24 },
  { team: 1, stat1Agst: 17, stat2Agst: 25, var1Agst: 'okay', var3Agst: 'nah', hereAgst: 24 }
]
```

Each object in our actual array of objects has >100 keys, and for this reason we are looking for a solution that specifically changes all key names other than `team`, rather than changing all keys with names ['stat1', 'stat2', 'var1', 'var3', 'here'] if possible.

Comment: Why close for `needs more focus`? the focus of the question is fine.

Comment: People will often VTC with that reason if the question doesn't show an attempt / code that you've tried so far - so I'm guessing that might be the reason why.

Comment: Probably because you haven't add any code that _you've_ attempted - you're just expecting us to write something for you, and that's not how this site is meant to work.

Comment: Fair enough, I typically work on the code a bit before, and additionally after. I have a working solution for the time being that I will post.

Comment: If you have working code why are you asking the question?

Comment: I'm not sure if my code is written well or not. double-nested for loop seems like a messy way to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve the result using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) as:

```js
const arr = [
  { team: 1, stat1: 17, stat2: 25, var1: "okay", var3: "nah", here: 24 },
  { team: 1, stat1: 17, stat2: 25, var1: "okay", var3: "nah", here: 24 },
  { team: 1, stat1: 17, stat2: 25, var1: "okay", var3: "nah", here: 24 },
];

const result = arr.map((o) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(o).map((key) =>
      key === "team" ? [key, o[key]] : [`${key}Agst`, o[key]]
    )
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working okay for me.

```js
arr = [
  { team: 1, stat1: 17, stat2: 25, var1: 'okay', var3: 'nah', here: 24 },
  { team: 1, stat1: 17, stat2: 25, var1: 'okay', var3: 'nah', here: 24 },
  { team: 1, stat1: 17, stat2: 25, var1: 'okay', var3: 'nah', here: 24 }
]

arr.forEach((row, index, theArray) => {
    let rowKeys = Object.keys(row).filter(key => key !== 'team');
    rowKeys.forEach(key => {
        theArray[index][`${key}Agst`] = theArray[index][key];
        delete theArray[index][key];
    });
});

console.log(arr);
```